# Magento 2.3.2 Element 'sequence': This element is not expected. Expected is ( module )

Tags: xml, magento2.3.2

I'm using module Sebwite/SmartSearch. When i try to command line:

```
php bin/magento dev:tests:run default
```

It show a bug:

```
Failed asserting that an array is empty.
D:\xampp7212\htdocs\alothemess\bigsale\dev\tests\static\testsuite\Magento\Test\Integrity\Xml\SchemaTest.php:45
D:\xampp7212\htdocs\alothemess\bigsale\vendor\magento\framework\App\Utility\AggregateInvoker.php:56
D:\xampp7212\htdocs\alothemess\bigsale\dev\tests\static\testsuite\Magento\Test\Integrity\Xml\SchemaTest.php:48

Data set: /app/code/Sebwite/SmartSearch/etc/module.xml
Error validating D:/xampp7212/htdocs/alothemess/bigsale/app/code/Sebwite/SmartSearch/etc/module.xml against urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd
Array
(
    [0] => Element 'sequence': This element is not expected. Expected is ( module ).
Line: 12

)
```

Content of file /app/code/Sebwite/SmartSearch/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 * Author: Sebwite
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sebwite_SmartSearch" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
    <sequence>
        <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
        <module name="Magento_Search"/>
    </sequence>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening **`module`** tag should have a closing tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 *
 * Author: Sebwite
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Sebwite_SmartSearch" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
      <sequence>
         <module name="Magento_CatalogSearch"/>
         <module name="Magento_Search"/>
      </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

Comment: I work fine. Thank you!